# How to fix event handler on static button in dynamic asp.net page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a user control that is not firing button click events properly. The button is static on the page, but the majority of the content on the page is managed dynamically with javascript and VB. When the button is clicked, none of the event handler's code is executed. I've tested it with break points in visual studio. The button click does cause page_load to execute, but the handler is never executed.

This is the definition of the button

```
<asp:Button  ID="btnUpdateVariables" runat="server" Text="Update Table" />
```

This is my page_load function

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ` ...
        ` Add / edit controls
        ` ...
        AddHandler btnUpdateVariables.Click, AddressOf updateVariables
        ` ...
        ` Add / edit controls
        ` ...
    End If
End Sub
```

updateVariables' declaration looks like this

```
Private Sub updateVariables(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdateVariables.Click
    `...
End Sub
```

Any help fixing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring the onclick method in the aspx markup?

```
<asp:Button  ID="btnUpdateVariables" runat="server" onclick="updateVariables" Text="Update Table" />
```